# IBM MQ First Failure

Tags: ibm-mq

I am trying to do any operation on the existing qmgrs or create another qmgr but I am getting this

error:

**AMQ7077E: You are not authorized to perform the requested operation.**

I did a search and found tasks about the length of username and password shouldn't be more than 12 characters, and I am using mqm as a username and password.

```
IBM MQ First Failure Symptom Report                                         | 
| =========================================                                   | 
|                                                                             |
| Date/Time         :- Wed March 08 2023 --:--:-- EET                         | 
| UTC Time          :-                                       | 
| UTC Time Offset   :- 120 (EET)                                              | 
| UTC Date/Time     :- 2023-03-08 18:42:28.701984 (1678300948701984)          | 
| Host Name         :- localhost.localdomain                                  | 
| Operating System  :- Linux 3.10.0-1127.el7.x86_64                           | 
| OS Details        :- CentOS Linux 7 (Core)                                  | 
| PIDS              :-                                               | 
| LVLS              :- 9.3.0.2                                                | 
| Product Long Name :- IBM MQ for Linux (x86-64 platform)                     | 
| Vendor            :- IBM                                                    | 
| O/S Registered    :- 1 (libmqmcs_r.so) Installed                            | 
| Data Path         :- /var/mqm                                               | 
| Installation Path :- /opt/mqm                                               | 
| Installation Name :- Installation1    (1)                                   | 
| License Type      :- Production                                             | 
| Probe Id          :- XY051070                                               | 
| Application Name  :- MQM                                                    | 
| Component         :- InitPrivateServices                                    | 
| Source filename   :- /build/jslot0/p930_P/src/lib/cs/unix/generic/amqxi     | 
|                      inx.c                                                  | 
| Line Number       :- 2725                                                   | 
| Build Date        :- Dec 14 2022                                            | 
| Build Level       :- p930-002-221214                                        | 
| Build Type        :- IKAP - (Production)                                    | 
| Effective UserID  :- 0 ()                                                   | 
| Real UserID       :- 0 ()                                                   | 
| Program Name      :- crtmqm                                                 | 
| Arguments         :- test                                                   | 
| Standard Streams  :- 0 1 2                                                  | 
| Addressing mode   :- 64-bit                                                 | 
| LANG              :- en_US.UTF-8                                            | 
| Process           :- 1987                                                   | 
| Process(Thread)   :- 1987                                                   | 
| Thread            :- 1    ProcessInit                                       | 
| Perf Counter      :- 2388170619672                                          | 
| UserApp           :- FALSE                                                  | 
| Last HQC          :- 0.0.0-0                                                | 
| Last HSHMEMB      :- 0.0.0-0                                                | 
| Last ObjectName   :-                                                        | 
| Major Errorcode   :- xecI_S_NOT_AUTHORIZED                                  | 
| Minor Errorcode   :- OK                                                     | 
| Probe Type        :- INCORROUT                                              | 
| Probe Severity    :- 1                                                      | 
| Probe Description :- AMQ6125E: An internal IBM MQ error has occurred.       | 
| FDCSequenceNumber :- 0                                                      | 
| Comment1          :- xcsGetpwuid failed to get password entry for process   |
|   with effective uid 1001.                                                  | 
| Comment2          :- Details: geteuid() returned 998; getpwuid_r(998)       |
|   failed with errno=0.                                                      | 
| Comment3          :- A user name of "UNKNOWN" will be used, which will      |
|   likely cause later authorisation failures. Note this FFST can be turned   |
|   off by exporting env var AMQ_NOFFST_PROCESS_UID.                          | 
|                                                                             |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+

MQM Function Stack
xcsInitialize
InitPrivateServices
xcsFFST

MQM Trace History
{ xppInitialiseDestructorRegistrations
} xppInitialiseDestructorRegistrations rc=OK
{ xcsGetEnvironmentInteger
-{ xcsGetEnvironmentString
-} xcsGetEnvironmentString rc=xecE_E_ENV_VAR_NOT_FOUND
} xcsGetEnvironmentInteger rc=xecE_E_ENV_VAR_NOT_FOUND
{ xcsGetEnvironmentInteger
-{ xcsGetEnvironmentString
-} xcsGetEnvironmentString rc=xecE_E_ENV_VAR_NOT_FOUND
} xcsGetEnvironmentInteger rc=xecE_E_ENV_VAR_NOT_FOUND
```

Comment: It says you are not authorized ... I suspect either your credentials aren't correct or might not be of high enough status to do the specific action.  As you were saying there is some info saying yep 12 is the limit here:
https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/when-userid-more-12-characters-invokes-mq-administration-commands-fdcs-are-generated-xy051169-initprivateservices-xcsgetpwuid-user-name-unknown

Comment: What does `id -a` show on the server?   The Effective/Real UserID show `0` which indicates `root` not mqm. Is your server using local /etc/passwd or AD or NIS or LDAP.

Comment: Josh might be onto something, it could be a directory right issue perhaps.    Something isn't authenticating for some reason.  I know the link warns of names and pw over 12 characters and that doesn't seem to be the case here, but it is behaving similar for some reason.

Comment: i am using local /etc/passwd,

Comment: this is the output of id, uid=1001(mqm) gid=1001(mqm) groups=1001(mqm),

Comment: easleyfixed, do you mean the mqm user credential, i am sure it's wright,

Comment: @easleyfixed, " Something isn't authenticating for some reason. I know the link warns of names and pw over 12 characters and that doesn't seem to be the case here, but it is behaving similar for some reason"  yes, i tried to search for this "Probe Id          :- XY051070" but i didn't find anything

Comment: And what is uid 998? Why does it not find a password entry for it?

Comment: @MoragHughson there is an entry for it,                                            polkitd:x:999:998:User for polkitd:/:/sbin/nologin

Comment: So why is polkitd being returned as your effective id by geteuid() ? Where does this user Id fit into this situation?

Comment: The user polkitd has uid 999 not 998 in your output, 998 is the primary group id.  Did you change the mqm user's UID from 998 to 1001?  Most MQ binaries under /opt/mqm/bin are set with setuid/setgid (`-r-sr-s---`), if you changed mqm uid or copied these files from a server where mqm had a different uid this could happen.